# GGPlot2 - Saving a list of some plots and running a PDF

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

Good Morning.

I'm trying to create a list of *some* of the graphs I have in my environment.

I tried this:

```
ggplot_list <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "ggplot"), mget(ls())) 
#list has 36 plots
pdf("plots6.pdf", width=11, height=8.5)
for (i in 1:36) {
    print(ggplot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

This creates a PDF of **all** the graphs.

So I tried to create a list of all the graphs I wanted in my PDF and replace `ggplot_list` with the new list name:

```
system_graphs <- list("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen")
```

and run

```
  pdf("plots7.pdf", width=11, height=8.5)
    for (i in 1:14) {
        print(system_graphs[[i]])
    }
    dev.off()
```

and then I got this error

```
for (i in 1:14) {
Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
   +     print(system_graphs[[i]])
[1] "one"
Error in +print(system_graphs[[i]]) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Could I get some assistance with this?

Comment: does `print(get(system_graphs[[i]]))` fix it?

Comment: Why yes it did. So simple. Thank you!